# mysql: how to optimize this when condition search + more?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have been trying to debug my search MYSQL search speeds and they are horrible (a couple of seconds to 2 minutes).

This is an example code for the search. Search complexity can become really complicated depending on the user requirements.

```
SELECT Device,Input,`W(m)`,`L(m)`,VDD,`Temp(C)`,Param,Value 
FROM `TABLE_NAME` 
WHERE (`Temp(C)`='110' OR `Temp(C)`='125' ) 
    AND (Device='ngear' ) 
    AND (Input='a' OR Input='b' OR Input='a' OR Input='b' OR Input='c' OR Input='b' ) 
    AND (Param='speed' OR Param='leakage' )
```

Please note this table has no indices and no primary key. This data isn't really relational as it contains statistical simulation data that is stored in MYSQL. This table has about 1 million rows of data.

Should I start indexing every column? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  TABLE_NAME  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    12278640    Using where
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, can you update your message to use table name 'TABLE_NAME'?

Comment: thanks! just wanted to be a generic as possible

Comment: Ok so your query is not using any indexes at all do you have any on the table? My suggestion is to add an index with the 'where' clause that narrows the data the most. As a guess temp should be the first column in the index. You want a compound index as well. The general rule of columns should start with the column that reduces the result set the most to the last being the most common value.

Comment: yup, I did that and it's so much faster! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a composite index, and properly require some redefine of your data type,
here is some general advice :

```
alter table MQUAL__TSMC_20G_v0d1_Robert_02122011
add index ( `Temp(C)`, Device, Input, Param);
```

And your query can be change to :-

```
where `Temp(C)` in(110, 125)
AND Device='ngear' 
AND Input in('a','b','c')
AND Param in('speed', 'leakage');
```

Due to lack of information of your schema,
so, data type should be :-

```
`Temp(C)` <-- int
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add an index with the 'where' clause that narrows the data the most. As a guess temp should be the first column in the index. You want a compound index as well. The general rule of columns should start with the column that reduces the result set the most to the last being the most common value.